# How to serialize swfWidgetformChoice multiple options to single field in database in symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I am using symfony 1.4 in a project and i need to store multiple
options in a single field .

I am using sfWidgetFormChoice Set up loooks like this:

```
    $status = Doctrine::getTable('Profile')->getStatuses();
    $this->widgetSchema['status'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
        'expanded'=>true,
        'choices'=>$status,
        'multiple'=>true
        ));
    $this->validatorSchema['status'] = new sfValidatorChoice( 
            array('choices'=>array_keys($status),
            'multiple'=>true, 'required'=>false
   ));
```

In my model I use the following to serialise multiple options into
single field.

```
  public function  setStatus($data) {
     $data = serialize($data);

     $this->_set('status', $data);

}
```

?>
Which works like a charm and save data as:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:7:"relaxed";i:1;s:8:"Inactive";}
```

However I'm am having difficulty retrieving the serialised string as
an array using the following in my model:

```
    public function  getStatus() {
     return unserialize($this->status);
    }
```

Am I missing something here? I get the following error:

Notice: Undefined property: Profile::$status in C:.../.././
Which doesnt make sense to me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doctrine has the "Array" type, which will automatically serialize/deserialize your array for you. Just specify the type of status as "Array" in your schema.yml file.

Comment: Thanks I only saw your answer now and manged to solve my problem by using the same solution as @Darmen suggested however I will try this option as it seems to be more correct

Answer (score 1):

```
public function  getStatus() {
    return unserialize($this->_get('status'));
}
```

However, you can use a solution mentioned by @greg0ire